# how to count total data from JSON use swift?

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I have a json at http://higoapps.com/api/content_api.php?&action=get_content_free&im=520 , what i want to do is count how many id_content inside that json. How to do it use swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data from the network using NSURLConnection or NSURLSession, then convert it to a collection using NSJSONSerialization. Then query the collection (array?) for its count.